# How to deal with unicode chars in python on windows

Tags: python, windows, unicode

I recently developed a PyQt app on Linux and I try to run it on Windows. I am not used to Windows at all.

At some places the program reads and interprets .csv file I created in Linux.

I read the .csv file line per line and for each line I detect a number of fields thanks to a field char separator (in my case ⎈ ).
On Linux the python program detects the correct number of fields but not on Windows.

When I print the lines on the terminal in Windows, they are unreadable.

What is the mean to tell python to deal with unicode strings the same way on both platforms without having to change the program in many places?

Here is a simplified example

**example.csv**

```
♆⎈deux⎈trois⎈quatre⎈cinq
♆⎈two⎈three⎈four⎈five
```

**testRead.py**

```
fileObj = open('example.csv', 'r')
#lines = fileObj.readlines()
char=None
end=False
line=''
stop_char='♆'
#read line after line
while True:
    line=''
    while True:
        char=fileObj.read(1)
        if(char ==stop_char):
            break
        if not char:
            break
        line += char

    if not char:
        #('Fin de fichier')
        end=True #we do not break here to allow the last line treatement
    print('line is '+line)
    if(line != '')  : #to avoid the first empty line  
        x_array=line.split('⎈')
        print('length of line is '+str(len(x_array)))
    if end:
        break
fileObj.close()
```

Output on linux

```
(venvbase) [jaaf@fedora project]$ python testRead.py
line is 
line is ⎈deux⎈trois⎈quatre⎈cinq

length of line is 5
line is ⎈two⎈three⎈four⎈five

length of line is 5
(venvbase) [jaaf@fedora project]$
```

**Output on Windows**

```
(.venv) PS E:\project> python testRead.py
line is â™†âŽˆdeuxâŽˆtroisâŽˆquatreâŽˆcinq
â™†âŽˆtwoâŽˆthreeâŽˆfourâŽˆfive

length of line is 1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I just added a simplified example on the initial post

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'♆⎈two⎈three⎈four⎈five'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'â™†âŽˆtwoâŽˆthreeâŽˆfourâŽˆfive'`… Try `open('example.csv', 'r', encoding='utf_8')`. Maybe define [Windows environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3.11/search.html?q=PYTHONIOENCODING&check_keywords=yes&area=default) `set PYTHONIOENCODING` -> `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`. Maybe `CHCP 65001` _before_ running `python testRead.py`. Maybe a combination of above steps…

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, after some reading I find this solution. Just telling the open function that we deal with utf-8

```
fileObj = open('example.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8')
```

which agree with the last comment

I think it’s preferable to changing environment variable in the OS which is not obvious for a non computer-scientist user.
I also cannot pass the -Xutf8 command line option that cannot be used when app is compiled with pyinstaller